# Solve the recurrence using backwards substitution

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relations

Here is what I have so far for this recurrence relation problem.

$$
\left\lbrace
\begin{array}{l}
x(0) = 0 \\
x(n) =  x(n-1) + n
\end{array}
\right.
$$
I have tried substituting to get $x (n-1)  = x (n-2) + n-1$, but this is where I'm getting stuck at.

Comment: Have you tried listing the first few terms?  This is a very well known sequence.

Comment: Note that this is not an homogeneus recurrence relation since there is an $n$.

Comment: @manooooh Regardless, it's pretty well known.

Comment: $\sum_{i=1}^{n}=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$

Answer (score 0):

Let's compute some of the first terms

$$x_1=x_0+1=0+1=1$$
$$x_2=x_1+2=0+1+2=3$$$$x_3=x_2+3=0+1+2+3=6$$

We see a pattern! We can rewrite the formula for $x_n$ as $$x_n=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n k$$This sequence is known as the [triangular numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number). The explicit formula for it is $$x_n=\frac{n\cdot(n+1)}2$$